# How to edit footer for macro-enables word document in 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was trying to edit footer in .dotm file. But it was giving me below error when document getting opened.

[image: Macro error]

I want to update footer in document but wasn't able to do it.

Can somebody help me how to edit footer in such case?

Answer (score 0):

In Word, go to File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Macro Settings and select "Disable all macros with notification" and also select "Trust access to the project VBA object model."  Also take a look at File > Options > Trust Center > Trusted Locations and add the location where your normal.dotm is stored.  Reference:  [Macros disabled in Normal.dotm template](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother/macros-disabled-in-normaldotm-template/216db5cc-5e8b-45b8-a8dd-722c49b1b33e)